# See when files were backed up?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, acronis-trueimage

Every day, my laptop uses Acronis True Image Home 2009 on Windows XP/SP3, to incrementally back up a certain directory tree to a second hard disk.

It creates files such as: `Data.tib`, `Data2.tib`, `Data3.tib`, …

Double clicking one of these files allows me to browse the backup data. However, I always see *all the data*, not just the data within an individual file.

Is it possible to see *which increments* have been made *on a certain day*, i.e. when certain files were backed up?

I now also [posted this question](http://forum.acronis.com/forum/41833) on the Acronis forums.

Comment: Incrementally updates in Acronis doesn't work like like you think it does.  Acronis updates every file it requires to update.

Comment: BTW, Acronis gets really bad reviews -- lots of complaints about unrecoverable data.

Comment: @Ramhound: Do you mean it doesn't back up deltas? If so, that doesn't matter. I just want to see which files were backed up yesterday.

Comment: @feklee - Acronis doesn't present this information.  It also wouldn't be possible if they didn't keep track of the deltas.  I learned very quickly that Incrementally updates doesn't save any room at all really.

Comment: @Ramhound The way I have set up Acronis *does* make incremental backups. The amount of backed up data varies from backup to backup, depending on how much has changed. And, yes, I have tested recovery successfully several times. Note that I use Acronis to back up a directory tree, not an entire partition.